# C++: Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have wrote coding and used function pointer in it, coding as bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//base class
class Base1 {
public:
        virtual void f() { cout << "Base1::f" << endl; }// virtual function
        virtual void g() { cout << "Base1::g" << endl; }// virtual function
        virtual void h() { cout << "Base1::h" << endl; }// virtual function

};

class Derive : public Base1 {
public:
        virtual void f() { cout << "Derive::f" << endl; }// virtual function
        virtual void g1() { cout << "Derive::g1" << endl; }
};

typedef void(*Fun)(void);

int main()
{
        Fun pFun = NULL;

        Derive d;
        int** pVtab = (int**)&d;

        //Base1's vtable
        //pFun = (Fun)*((int*)*(int*)((int*)&d+0)+0);
        pFun = (Fun)pVtab[0][0];
        pFun();

        //pFun = (Fun)*((int*)*(int*)((int*)&d+0)+1);
        pFun = (Fun)pVtab[0][1];
        pFun();

        return 0;
}
```

But when I run the code with g++ in Linux, it shows :

```
Derive::f
Segmentation fault
```

I want to know why and how to fix it.

Comment: What makes you think the vtable is there?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have read some book and that tell me！

Comment: This code will not be portable. It is a bad idea to try and get into the VMT yourself. If you need a pointer to a method use that instead of doing fancy things like trying to get a pointer to a function by accessing the VMT.

Answer (score 1):

```
pFun = (Fun)pVtab[0][0];
 pFun();
```

Simply happens to align with the first declared function in the Derive class

```
//pFun = (Fun)*((int*)*(int*)((int*)&d+0)+1); 
pFun = (Fun)pVtab[0][1];
 pFun();
```

Now you're offsetting the *pointer* of Derived by sizeof(*int), and expect it to align with a function. This is very unlikely to work.